# How to customize Scala PrioriryQueue to handle duplicates?

Tags: scala, priority-queue

I have a list of orders to put into a PriorityQueue[OrderQueue], the price is used to decide the order, the lower the price the higher the orderQueue. Each element of the PriorityQueue is a OrderQueue so that it can handle the orders with same price.
When price is the same then the order should be appended into the end of the OrderQueue.
Is it possible to implement this using standard PriorityQueue?
If not, do I have to implement the Heap from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TreeMap` instead. It is implemented as heap so should have same performance characteristics.
It supports `head` and `headOption` operations from `SortedMap` and at the same time `update`.

```
type Price = Long
type Order = String
val queue = new mutable.TreeMap[Price, mutable.Queue[Order]]()
val subQueue: mutable.Queue[Order] = queue.getOrElseUpdate(100L, mutable.Queue.empty)
val highestPriority: Option[(Price, mutable.Queue[Order])] = queue.headOption
```